# Explode a string via regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to explode a string like this:

```
([a:b:c:d:...])
```

I have a code that partially works

```
([^\(\[\]\):])+
```

but it's not ideal since I need to make sure the string found is within the ([ ]) tags. But whenever I add them to the regexp, it stops working (can't find any matches).

```
\(\[([^\(\[\]\):])+\]\)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using this website to test them regular expressions

http://myregextester.com/index.php

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why are you trying to do this in one shot? strip off the `([` and `])` then just explode on `:`

Comment: What does "explode" mean to you? For the string you've given, what is the expected output? What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry it's php. It's a common term in php to explode a string. It means to split a string into an array, using a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two parts, first match the stuff between the brackets

```
\(\[([^)\]]*)\]\)
```

which will put the inner contents in to `matches[1]`, then simply explode/split on `:`

Comment: Your approach seems to work. But why can't all be done in one shot?

Comment: @miroki123: How? You want to explode on colons, but you want to discard the brackets. That's a two-step process. *Unless* you don't "explode" but rather "match" the stuff inbetween, but this approach seems simpler to me.

Comment: Worked much better than I had hoped for. Thanks.